# How to read, update and send a new e-mail using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I have connected my Azure Logic Apps to get triggered connected with a Microsoft Exchange Online Mailbox.

When an e-mail comes,

1st Step:- I need to extract the From Address, To Address, Subject, Body
2nd Step:- I need to create a new e-mail using the extracted details from the received e-mail.
3rd Step:- Send the newly created e-mail to the receipient.

Comment: Hasn't this problem been solved yet? You can tell me, maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to my understanding, you can use the `When a new email arrives (V3)` trigger, and I don’t think you need to extract the received email information, because the trigger will automatically parse the received email information, you only need to create the `Send an email (V2)` operation in the next step.

In the `Send an email (V2)` action, you can use the received email information parsed by the trigger, and the email will be sent automatically.

The design of the logic app is as follows:

[image]

The following is the received mail information parsed by the trigger:

[image]

Maybe you can refer to this official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/tutorial-process-email-attachments-workflow#send-email-notifications).